# Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado paisControler

Tags: java, jsf

Ao tentar iniciar uma página do sistema mostra este erro.

Vou colocar os códigos:

DAO

```
package br.com.netsoft.desif.dao.endereco;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import br.com.netsoft.desif.model.endereco.PaisEntity;

public class PaisDao implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1402488530698938353L;

    final private String hql = " p FROM PaisEntity p ";

    EntityManager em;

    public List<PaisEntity> listarPaises() {

        StringBuilder hqlSelect = new StringBuilder(hql);

        final String query = "SELECT " + hqlSelect;

        Query querySelect = em.createQuery(query);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<PaisEntity> resultList = querySelect.getResultList();

        return resultList;

    }

}
```

ENTITY

```
package br.com.netsoft.desif.model.endereco;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

public class PaisEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7784827196506672790L;
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pai_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "enderecos.end_pais_pai_id_seq", sequenceName = "enderecos.end_pais_pai_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "enderecos.end_pais_pai_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "pai_descricao")
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

}
```

CONTROLLER

```
package br.com.netsoft.desif.controler.endereco;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import br.com.netsoft.desif.dao.endereco.PaisDao;
import br.com.netsoft.desif.model.endereco.PaisEntity;

@ManagedBean(name = "paisControler")
@RequestScoped
public class PaisControler extends PaisEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8396738159447021720L;

    private List<PaisEntity> paises;

    private PaisDao paisDao;

    public List<PaisEntity> getPaises() {
        if (paises == null) {
            return new ArrayList<PaisEntity>();
        }
        return paises;
    }

    public void setPaises(List<PaisEntity> paises) {
        this.paises = paises;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Página inicial de países.");
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        List<PaisEntity> paisesBusca = paisDao.listarPaises();

        ArrayList<PaisEntity> paises = (ArrayList<PaisEntity>) paisDao.listarPaises();

        for (Iterator<?> iterator = paises.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            PaisEntity pais = (PaisEntity) iterator.next();
            pais.setId(pais.getId());
            pais.setDescricao(pais.getDescricao());
            paises.add(pais);
        }

        this.setPaises(paises);
    }

    public String getMensagem() {
        return "Teste";
    }

}
```

VISÃO

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Hello JSF!</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
          #{paisControler.mensagem}

        <h:dataTable var="pais" value="#{paisControler.paises}">

            <h:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{pais.id}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column headerText="Year">
                <h:outputText value="#{pais.descricao}" />
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>

    </h:body>

    </html>
```

Erro:

```
mar 21, 2017 8:08:40 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/public/index.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /public/index.xhtml: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado paisControler
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado paisControler
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.netsoft.desif.controler.endereco.PaisControler.init(PaisControler.java:39)
    ... 54 more

mar 21, 2017 8:08:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/desif] threw exception [Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado paisControler] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.netsoft.desif.controler.endereco.PaisControler.init(PaisControler.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: @guilherme solicite o merge entre as duas contas [**neste formulario**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact), para que consiga editar e comentar nesta pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O log já está apontando o erro:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at br.com.netsoft.desif.controler.endereco.PaisControler.init(PaisControler.java:39)
```

Esse NPE ocorre no seguinte trecho de código:

```
List<PaisEntity> paisesBusca = paisDao.listarPaises();
```

O problema é porque você não injetou o paisDao, então ele é nulo aqui e por isso a chamada do seu método `listarPaises` ocasiona o NPE. Adicione a injeção desse atributo no MBean e o problema será resolvido.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo ?

Comment: Você está usando Spring ou CDI no teu projeto?

Comment: CDI

<!-- CDI -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
   <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: Então coloca apenas um @Inject em paisDao.

Comment: Alterei para, mas não funcionou.

public class PaisControler extends PaisEntity {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -8396738159447021720L;

 private List<PaisEntity> paises;

 @Inject
 PaisDao paisDao;

Comment: Só pra testar, chama o construtor do Dao diretamente para ver se o problema é com o @Inject.

Comment: Assim funciona, mas ai com o debug o erro está no DAO.

@PostConstruct
 public void init() {
  System.out.println("Página inicial de países.");

  paisDao = new PaisDao();

Comment: Ai o erro acontece nesta linha:

Query querySelect = em.createQuery(query);

Comment: Sei que é quase a mesma idéia, mas após pesquisar e fazer algumas alterações, não consegui evoluir.

Comment: O erro é a chamada do listarPaises() porque o paisDao tá nulo. Você só precisa inicializá-lo, seja por construtor, seja por injeção de dependências.

Comment: Fiz assim:

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

Mas não adiantou.

Comment: Mais algo que posso fazer ??

Comment: Inicia o entityManager sem injeção de dependências, para ver se funciona. Você chamaria o Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory e depois o createEntityManager para inicializar em.

Comment: Fiz assim:

EntityManager em;

 public List<PaisEntity> listarPaises() {
  
  StringBuilder hqlSelect = new StringBuilder(hql);

  final String query = "SELECT" + hqlSelect;

  EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PaisEntity");
  
  EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
  
  Query querySelect = manager.createQuery(query);
  
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<PaisEntity> resultList = querySelect.getResultList();

  return resultList;

 }

Comment: Deu este erro:



Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named PaisEntity
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
 at br.com.netsoft.desif.dao.endereco.PaisDao.listarPaises(PaisDao.java:28)
 at br.com.netsoft.desif.controler.endereco.PaisControler.init(PaisControler.java:43)

Acho que não está persistindo.